# Google Map Location constructor with general location type

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I have been using Google maps api to get customer to a specific location using a constructor like this

```
new google.maps.LatLng(42.999, 54.000);
```

With the exact longitude and latitude as the arguments.  What I want to do now is not use the lat, long option and use a keyword like rest area that would bring up the closet rest area.  I am not quite finding it in Google map api here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Can some one help me come up with a constrctor that can take a key word and locate the nearest one in googLe maps.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use the google geocoding API.

Basically you do a request to google with a search string and it returns an object containing the long/lat for areas it may have found... There's a lot of options in there and you can do fairly neat tricks which are already carefully explained by google themselves.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

There are some limitations to the # of requests you can make per-day. To keep this to a minimum you can ofcourse make a server side script that pre-fetches results for things that will be re-used (for example the long/lat for office location of a large enterprise which may have a dot on a map on the website...).

Simplest way would be to make a [json](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON) request with a few parameters and parse the return json in js, like getting the long/lat of the first result returned.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use keyword search for things around a particular location. I would suggest using the Places library of the Google Maps API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_searches

This allows you to search by category or by keyword over Google's datastore of 10s of millions of Places.